# Blur filter issues cs50

Tags: c, cs50

This is my code for blur from filter lesson of CS50x course.  When I make this, the image pixels stay exactly the same and don't even change. Could anyone tell me where I went wrong?

The language is C. The reasons for my steps are shown in the header before each step. Basically, I iterate through all the pixels and add the neighbouring pixels to it then divide by the total number of additions along with the original pixel.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    RGBTRIPLE total[height][width];
    // Save all the initial colour values into a new variable
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Loop through the pixels and calculate average value for each
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Clear the pixel's colour values
            total[i][j].rgbtRed = 0;
            total[i][j].rgbtBlue = 0;
            total[i][j].rgbtGreen = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            // Loops through the blocks 1 column and 1 row away from the pixel
            for(int k = i - 1; k < i + 2; k++)
            {
                // If k is less than 0 or more than height, skip that step
                if(k < 0 || k > (height - 1))
                {
                    return;
                }
                for(int l = j - 1; l < j + 2; l++)
                {
                    // If l is less than 0 or more than wddth, skip that step
                    if(l < 0 || l > (width - 1))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    total[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[k][l].rgbtRed + total[i][j].rgbtRed;
                    total[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[k][l].rgbtBlue + total[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                    total[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[k][l].rgbtGreen + total[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
           // Divide the total by the number of counter
           image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((float) total[i][j].rgbtRed / counter);
           image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((float) total[i][j].rgbtGreen / counter);
           image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((float) total[i][j].rgbtBlue / counter);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: The `return` statements in your loops aren't going to help. Try replacing them with `continue`. (A `return` statement will exit the function immediately; `continue` will skip the current iteration of the loop and continue from the next one.)

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything.  When you create the new array that represents your new image, then you need to return that and only that.